# Breeze SaveChanges: possible to just skip the core part?

Tags: breeze

Using DTO's, I dont' need Breeze to actually save the data in the database. I do it myself.
But I would still need Breeze to correctly manage SaveResult. I've tried to create the SaveResult myself, but by simply passing the created objects in the Entity list, I then miss things such as the id fix on the client.

So I would really really want Breeze to be able to perform the SaveChanges process until the end somehow.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally decided to add my own  List of KeyMappings 
to a manually created SaveResult. Works like a charm.